# Change node position of the graph using Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am using the Neo4j Desktop Version 1.0.18 (1.0.18.81). I want to create a graph where the "source" node's position will be in upper side and the "target" node's position will be in the lower side. I have already created several graph using Neo4j where the nodes position of the graph generated randomly.I have attached my graph where the source and target node's position created automatically.Is there any way to do this in Neo4j?Please help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j itself isn't for generating visualizations of graphs; it's for storing and retrieving data in a graph. As such, the visualization options are limited. In the desktop client you can click and drag nodes returned by a query to lock them in whatever location you want.

There is separate software for graph visualizations, but I haven't used any of it so I can't make a recommendation.